# Website showing � even though I am working with utf-8

Tags: mysql, encoding, utf-8, pymysql

I am using pymysql to make the following insert into my test table.
First I set up the connection and specify the charset and set unicode to True:

`conn=pymysql.connect(host=*ip*,user='simao_simao',password=*mypass*,database=*mydatabase*,use_unicode=True, charset="utf8")`

Then I successfully insert the values into my table.

```
cur = conn.cursor()
sql = "Insert into test (colx, coly) Values('%s', 'not_relevant')"%(tag)
>>> sql
"Insert into test (colx, coly) Values('£26,302 - £35,225 + 20% R','not_relevant')"
>>> cur.execute(sql)
1
```

[image: My table is utf-8 unicode ready]

My html code includes:

```
meta charset="UTF-8"
```

Still I get the � symbol instead of the £ in my webpage. Any idea what can be wrong?

Comment: So you get an error **AND** the � replacement character?

Comment: I don't get any error. I just get the replacement when the results are fetched into my website.

Comment: Sorry, I got what you meant now. The title is referring to a previous error I had, I am going to edit it now.

Comment: Are you really hardcoding the data in your script or are you reading the data from an external source, like a text/csv file?

Comment: I am pulling data from a website using pandas. But it turns out that I get the pound symbol replaced even when I manually do an insert directly in my table.

Comment: Ok, that's a very important piece of information. It sounds like the encoding of your data is not 'utf-8'. Can you verify?

Comment: I validated that it is not due to the python script the following way: droped the table in my database. Created a new table with the same name as the previous one (set the encoding to utf-8 unicode) inserted new records typing each one manually. Absolutely no crawling, no python, nothing involved, just hard coded SQL script. Still I get the unwanted symbol.

Comment: Again, your data does not seem to be UTF-8 encoded. How are you "typing each one manually"?

Comment: I am using my phpMyAdmin panel typing the following querry by hand, and running it:
     INSERT INTO `simao_test`.`table_1` (`VacId`, `DateInsert`, `JobTitle`, `Location`, `Url`, `ExternalDate`, `JobId`, `JobType`, `Salary`, `Profession`, `Sub_Profession`, `Sector`, `Description`) VALUES ('123', '2016-09-03 10:22:27', 'Sales Assistant', 'London', 'http://example.com', '2016-09-01', 'KJDKA6', 'Full time', '£23,000 - £32,000', 'Sales Assistant', 'Assistant', 'No Sctor', 'No description');

The salary keeps being shown with wrong character.

Comment: Does it show correctly in phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Yes. It shows the "£" symbol perfectly there.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38363567/1766831

Follow the debugging tip with `SELECT ... HEX...` to see if the `£` is correctly stored as `C2A3` (utf8), not `A3` (latin1) or `C382C2A3` (double-encoded).

Provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to verify that the column is utf8 or utf8mb4.

Verify that the code starts with `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` so that the encoding is utf8.  (That covers one of the possible causes of black-diamond; see the link.)

If that is not enough, check more Python notes here:
http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#python

Comment: Debugged it and it is correctly stored in C2A3.
This is extracted from create table:
`Salary` varchar(75) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
I am not using python now
I droped the table in my database. Created a new table with the same name as the previous one (set the encoding to utf-8 unicode) inserted new records typing each one manually. Absolutely no crawling, no python, nothing involved, just hard coded SQL script. 
This is probably a problem with the php code but I don't see why, I am using:
<code> <meta charset="UTF-8"> </code>

Comment: The Hex I got for this value: '£23,000 - £32,000' was: C2A332332C303030202D20C2A333322C303030

Comment: C2A3 - good, so it sounds like the web browser is not rendering correctly.  The meta should be right.  "Manually typed"??  There has to be some kind of client.  That client needs to be encoding in utf8, not latin1.  That client needs to be connecting with utf8, such as using `SET NAMES utf8`.